# ArrayAdapter is raw type warning?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am creating a list view layout and receive an `ArrayAdapter` warning. The error message is below. The warning message is pointing to the following text:

```
new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());
```

Any assistance will be helpful

warning message:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type ArrayAdapter is a raw type.
>   References to generic type ArrayAdapter should be
>   parameterized LoginList.java  /LoginPlus/src/com/loginplus/home   line
>   95    Java Problem

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
loginListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());
    loginList.setAdapter(loginListAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use something like `ArrayAdapter<Type>` where "Type" is replaced with the actual type used by the ArrayAdapter.

For example:

`ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>`

As the warning says, this is because ArrayAdapter is generic, so you *should* specify the type it refers to so that the compiler can check that everything is good at compile time.

You can read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html).

Comment: The read more link is no longer valid.